# How do you add a forms controls to a cell in a Excel spreadsheet for each row

Tags: c#, excel

How do i add a forms control in excel to a cell, I know I can draw it, but I need to make it a member of each row and it's values attached to that cell/row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this but the easiest, assuming Excel 2007 is:

```
Set cb = MyWorkSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(left, top, width, height)
cb.LinkedCell = "$A$1"
cb.Display3DShading = True
```

You have to experiment a little with placement as I don't think there is a direct way to align the control with a particular cell.  Another way would be to use the `Shapes` collection of the worksheet:

```
Set shape = MyWorkSheet.Shapes.AddFormControl(xlCheckBox, l, t, w, h)
```

However, keep in mind that the above method returns a `Shape` object and not a `CheckBox` object so you can't manipulate its properties directly.  There are similar methods to the above like using the `OLEObjects` collection but that's just adding more pain.

Comment: Nope.  Straight VBA.  If you copy and paste that into a macro (with suitable values in the Add method) you'll get a check box linked to cell A1.

Comment: Also note, while this tells me how to add it, it is never really in the cell, but gave accpeted answer as the real answer seems to be NO you cannot put a forms control in a cell.

Comment: By "add a forms control in excel to a cell", I took you to mean 'aligned with' (i.e. the control will move with the cell) and not 'embedded in'.  You're right--only text or a formula can be added to a cell.

Comment: @gvkv, I have same problem, But my worksheet does not have CheckBoxes properties!